# ContextMenu with ItemsSource and Separators

Tags: wpf

I'd like to bind the `ItemsSource` of a `ContextMenu` to a collection in my view model and I'd like the `ContextMenu` to show `Separator`s as well.

Usually a `Separator` in a `ContextMenu` is rendered as a horizontal line. But this doesn't seem to work in my case. Maybe you can shed some light into this?

I know that view models should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` but for the sake of simplicity I stripped my example of all unnecessary stuff.

**MenuItemViewModel.vb:**

```
Public Class MenuItemViewModel
    Public Property IsSeparator As Boolean
    Public Property Caption As String
End Class
```

**MainViewModel.vb:**

```
Public Class MainViewModel
    Private ReadOnly _items As List(Of MenuItemViewModel)

    Public Sub New()
        _items = New List(Of MenuItemViewModel)
        _items.Add(New MenuItemViewModel With {.Caption = "Item 1"})
        _items.Add(New MenuItemViewModel With {.IsSeparator = True, .Caption = "Sep 1"})
        _items.Add(New MenuItemViewModel With {.Caption = "Item 2"})
        _items.Add(New MenuItemViewModel With {.Caption = "Item 3"})
        _items.Add(New MenuItemViewModel With {.IsSeparator = True, .Caption = "Sep 2"})
        _items.Add(New MenuItemViewModel With {.Caption = "Item 4"})
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Items As List(Of MenuItemViewModel)
        Get
            Return _items
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

**MenuItemTemplateSelector.vb:**

```
Public Class MenuItemTemplateSelector
    Inherits DataTemplateSelector

    Public Property ItemTemplate As DataTemplate
    Public Property SeparatorTemplate As DataTemplate

    Public Overrides Function SelectTemplate(item As Object, container As DependencyObject) As DataTemplate
        Dim menuItem As MenuItemViewModel

        menuItem = TryCast(item, MenuItemViewModel)

        If (menuItem IsNot Nothing) AndAlso menuItem.IsSeparator Then
            Return Me.SeparatorTemplate
        Else
            Return Me.ItemTemplate
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="mit">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="mst">
            <Separator />
            <!--<Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />-->
        </DataTemplate>

        <local:MenuItemTemplateSelector x:Key="mits"
                                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource mit}"
                                        SeparatorTemplate="{StaticResource mst}" />

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Right click me">
            <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource mits}" />
            </TextBox.ContextMenu>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you right click on the `TextBox` the `ContextMenu` pops up, but the `Separator`s are not rendered as horizontal lines, they instead look like common menu items but without caption, They even blue up when the mouse hovers over them.

Since they have a caption in the view model and this caption doesn't show, it seems that it's really not using the defined `ItemTemplate`, but what template does it use? Or does a simple `<Separator />` does not create a horizontal line anymore)?

How can I get a default separator to show up?

---

**Edit:** It seems, that my `Separator` gets wrapped inside a `MenuItem`, but how can I avoid that?

Comment: Without creating a derived ContextMenu class it is not possible to avoid that a MenuItem is generated for every element in the ItemsSource collection. A simple and straighforward (although not really MVVM) approach would be to assign a collection of UIElements to the ContextMenu's ItemsSource property. The collection would contain MenuItems and Separators.

Comment: Separators are visual elements that should be defined in the view. Why are you creating view models with only a `Caption` and an `IsSeparator` property? Do you really need this `MenuItemViewModel` type?

Comment: It's just an example. The `MenuItemViewModel` would later contain for instance the `Command` to bind the menu item to. And right now my model contains "functions" that have a property called "BeginGroup". If this property is set ther should be a `Separator` infront of it.

Comment: Write a ControlTemplate for MenuItem which contains only `<Separator/>`. Use a trigger in `ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle` to swap in that controltemplate for menu items where `IsSeparator` equals `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Ed Plunkett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424129/ed-plunkett)'s comment I got rid of the "MenuItemTemplateSelector.vb" file and all the corresponding window resources ("mit", "mst" and "mits").

Then I added the following new window resources...

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="mist" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Separator />
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="mict" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Caption}" />
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="cmics" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource mict}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSeparator}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource mist}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

...and changed my `TextBox` to...

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Right click me">
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource cmics}" />
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

...and everything works fine.

Thank you [Ed Plunkett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424129/ed-plunkett).