# Struggling with HierarchicalDataTemplate in ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'd like to be able to bind the `ItemsSource` of a `ContextMenu` to a `Collection` in my view model, show `Separator`s in the `ContextMenu`, and the `ItemsSource` has to be hierarchical (every level of the hierarchy will look the same).

In [one of my other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269576/contextmenu-with-itemssource-and-separators) I managed to be able to show menu items and separators in a data bound `ContextMenu`, but now I struggle with making the `ItemsSource` hierarchical.

Right now I don't know what's going on, maybe you can enlighten me?

Here's my code again (simplified to be short, but working):

**MenuItemViewModel.vb**

```
Public Class MenuItemViewModel
    Implements ICommand

    Public Event CanExecuteChanged As EventHandler Implements ICommand.CanExecuteChanged

    Public Property IsSeparator As Boolean
    Public Property Caption As String
    Private ReadOnly _subItems As List(Of MenuItemViewModel)

    Public Sub New(createItems As Boolean, level As Byte)
        _subItems = New List(Of MenuItemViewModel)

        If createItems Then
            _subItems.Add(New MenuItemViewModel(level < 4, level + 1) With {.Caption = "SubItem 1"})
            _subItems.Add(New MenuItemViewModel(False, level + 1) With {.IsSeparator = True, .Caption = "SubSep 1"})
            _subItems.Add(New MenuItemViewModel(level < 4, level + 1) With {.Caption = "SubItem 2"})
        End If
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property SubItems As List(Of MenuItemViewModel)
        Get
            Return _subItems
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Command As ICommand
        Get
            Return Me
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Execute(ByVal parameter As Object) Implements ICommand.Execute
        MessageBox.Show(Me.Caption)
    End Sub

    Public Function CanExecute(ByVal parameter As Object) As Boolean Implements ICommand.CanExecute
        Return True
    End Function

End Class
```

The view model for each menu item on each level has a `Caption` to show in the context menu, an `IsSeparator` flag to indicate whether it's a separator or a functional menu item, a `Command` to be bound to when being a functional menu item and of course a `SubItems` collection containing functional menu items and separators down to a certain hierarchy level.

**MainViewModel.vb**

```
Public Class MainViewModel
    Private ReadOnly _items As List(Of MenuItemViewModel)

    Public Sub New()
        _items = New List(Of MenuItemViewModel)
        _items.Add(New MenuItemViewModel(True, 0) With {.Caption = "Item 1"})
        _items.Add(New MenuItemViewModel(False, 0) With {.IsSeparator = True, .Caption = "Sep 1"})
        _items.Add(New MenuItemViewModel(True, 0) With {.Caption = "Item 2"})
        _items.Add(New MenuItemViewModel(True, 0) With {.Caption = "Item 3"})
        _items.Add(New MenuItemViewModel(False, 0) With {.IsSeparator = True, .Caption = "Sep 2"})
        _items.Add(New MenuItemViewModel(True, 0) With {.Caption = "Item 4"})
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Items As List(Of MenuItemViewModel)
        Get
            Return _items
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

The main view model does only have an `Items` collection containing functional menu items as well as separators.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="mist" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Separator />
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="mict" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Caption}" Command="{Binding Command}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}" />
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="cmics" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource mict}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSeparator}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource mist}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Right click me">
            <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource cmics}">
                    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}" />
                    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBox.ContextMenu>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The window resources contain two `ControlTemplate`s "mist" and "mict" and a `Style` "cmics" that switches between the two `ControlTemplate`s depending on the value of the `IsSeparator` flag. This works fine as long as the `ItemsSource` is not hierarchical (see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269576/contextmenu-with-itemssource-and-separators)).

If my `Style` "cmics" is attached to the `ItemContainerStyle` of the `ContextMenu` only (as in my example code) then it looks like this:

[image]

The first level works but the others don't. This doesn't change when attaching my `Style` "cmics" to the `ItemContainerStyle` of the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` as well.

If I only attach my `Style` "cmics" to the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` then it looks like this:

[image]

The first level doesn't show captions and separators, the second level works and the other levels don't work.

So, how can I persuade the `ContextMenu` to use my `Style` "cmics" as the `ItemContainerStyle` for every hierarchy level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214027/how-to-correctly-bind-a-viewmodel-which-include-separators-to-wpfs-menu).

I had to create an empty view model just for the separators and a class that derives from `ItemContainerTemplateSelector` to return the `DataTemplate` that belongs to the type of the menu item ("MenuItemViewModel" or "SeparatorViewModel").

The linked article should be self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

I just did some changes to your (TextBox) in Xaml portion. Have a look at this,

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Right click me">
            <TextBox.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                    <Button Content="{Binding Caption}" Command="{Binding Command}" Background="Red"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TextBox.Resources>
            <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource cmics}"/>
            </TextBox.ContextMenu>
        </TextBox>
```

Basically I have removed your ContexttMenu ItemTemplate and added under TextBox.Resources a hierarchical data template.

Inside the data template, I just now added a radio button. You can change the content as per your needs.

Let me know if this solves your problem or else needed any other help.

Comment: But this shows sub-level menu upto 4 levels. I am not sure if this is required or intended to you. But have a look into it, if not required then hope you can make some changes accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately in the lower levels the separators are not rendered as separators (like in the top level), they are rendered as red buttons as well (because my style is not used in the lower levels). I'll try to play with it to make it work the way I want it.

Comment: That is because I have added Button inside Hierarchical data template. Replace it with your content of what ever you want to show it there like you did for first level menu. I hope you should be able to do it.

Comment: That's the problem, everything I put in there instead of your button gets wrapped inside a `MenuItem`. If I switch your button with a `ContentControl` with my style, I get a `MenuItem` wrapped inside another `MenuItem` or a `Separator` wrapped inside a `MenuItem` (depending on `IsSeparator`). That's why I need to use `ItemContainerStyle` but that doesn't work (at least I didn't get it to work the way I like it to work).